# Linux Mint 20.3 grub-install /dev/mmcblkX failed - fatal error

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, acer, mmc

I've been beating my head against the keys trying to get Mint to install on an Acer 2-in-1. It does not have Legacy boot support and only has UEFI. I have made sure all BIOS options are correct such as disabling secure boot.

I boot into the Linux Mint live USB and try to run the installer. Everything goes fine until the `grub-install /dev/mmcblk1 failed` message appears. It supposedly writes all the partitions correctly after the install fails, just no grub??

I am NOT dual booting, I only want Mint on this laptop. I can't view any logs because the installer immediately quits upon failing (REALLY bad design). All I can see is `cannot set efi variable boot0000` and a plethora of other errors titled `interrupted system call`. I've been browsing google all day with different queries and still no luck. Maybe it has something to do with the MMC storage since it's not technically a SATA device (it shows up in Disks as an SD CARD lol). I have formatted with both MBR and GPT, as well as manually created each partition for swap, fs, and efi. Any help will be very appreciated!

Trying to mount all partitions after installer fail, and chrooting into it to `grub-install` manually, results in something like:

> /efi/boot/grub.cfg.new cannot be found. Directory doesn't exist`.

`update-grub2` also does not work.